# Nmake can't locate files within a docker mount

Tags: docker, compilation, mount, nmake

I have a docker container I use to compile a project, build a setup and export it out of the container. For this I mount the checked out sources (using `$(Build.SourcesDirectory):C:/git/` in the volumes section of the TFS docker run task) and an output folder in 2 different folders. Now my project contains a submodule which is also correctly checked out, all the files are there. However, when my script executes nmake I get the following error:

`Cannot find file: \ContainerMappedDirectories\347DEF6A-D43B-48C0-A5DF-CE228E5A10FD\src\Submodule\Submodule.pro`

Where the path of the mapped container maps to `C:/git/` inside the windows docker container(running on a windows host). I was able to start the docker container with an interactive powershell and mount the folder and find out the following things:

1. All the files are there in the container.
2. **When doing `docker cp project/ container:C:/test/` and running my build script it finds all the files and compiles successfully.**
3. when copying the mounted project within docker with powershell and starting the build script it also works.

So it seems nmake has trouble traversing a mounted container within docker. Any idea how to fix this? I'd rather avoid copying the project into the container because that takes quite some time as compared to simply mounting the checked out project.

Comment: why does the error message contain '\' backslashes? When you 'exec' into your running container, are you able to see all of the mounted directories and the files in them? Have you looked at the permissions on them?

Comment: yes all the mounted files are where they should be(see #1). As I said my mountpoint is directly on C and the folder it mounts into is called git. So \ContainerMappedDirectories\ has to be in the docker root, the hash after that has to be the mount folder and \src\ is the first subfolder of my mounted folder. Already checked permissions, that doesn't seem to be it.